# How do I get the id I need from this JSON response from within a JS file

Tags: javascript, json

I have made an AJAX call from my JS file and I got a response like this (there are many more properties returned, but to simplify I am showing the JSON in this question like this:

```
{"release":"{\"avatar_url\": null, \"created\": \"2015-11-16T16:42:16+00:00\", \"guest_access_url\": null, \"id\": 2168982}","data":"Success"}
```

What I need is the value of the `"id"` field above response object

I tried `response.release.id, response.release["id"]` etc , didn't work.

Comment: Are you using JQuery? Or, is this a basic, native XMLHttpRequest? You may have to actually tell it to parse the string as JSON (`obj = JSON.parse(response.responseText)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `response.release` is another json so it needs to be parsed to object otherwise you cannot evaluate it. 
Hoping your success callback is like below will work.

```
success = function(response)  {
   // If response is an object then access else parse it to object      

   var id = JSON.parse(response.release).id;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Because the release itself is another json, it needs to parsed separately and access the id variable as suggested by Navoneel

Comment: I got it in a similar way using jQuery : var te = response;
                    var releaseid =  $.parseJSON(te.release).id;

Answer (score -1):

I guess if the json you paste is what you got, probably you have received it as string and not like a JSON object.

So there are 2 solutions for that:

```
var response = '{"release":"{\"avatar_url\": null, \"created\": \"2015-11-16T16:42:16+00:00\", \"guest_access_url\": null, \"id\": 2168982}","data":"Success"}' //This is the response data you get from ajax call
response = JSON.parse(response);
```

Now the variable response has the `json` object of the string the ajax call returned. So to access to the value you need you could do as you say `response.release.id`

Comment: When answering, it's best not to include a solution that requires an additional library that the OP is not already including. If you do, however, please note it in the answer so the OP can decide whether or not he/she is willing and able to incur the additional overhead (in this case of jQuery).